# Sort object of a class in java in most efficient way

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, oop, collections

I have Car class which has variable distance. I want to sort objects of car class with in most efficient way. I have tried below code for sorting but it is not an efficient way. Can any one help me with most efficient way of coding.

```
for(int j=0;j<get_car.no_of_cars;j++)
{
   for(int i=j;i<get_car.no_of_cars;i++)
   {

        if(get_car.Hundai[j].distance_covered>get_car.Hundai[i].distance_covered)                            
        {
            A[i]=get_car.Hundai[j];
            get_car.Hundai[j]=get_car.Hundai[i];
            get_car.Hundai[i]= A[i];        
        }
   }
}
```

In above code huandai is car object.

Comment: Use `Arrays#sort` and provide a custom `Comparator<Car>` for it.

Comment: You can use comparable or comparator.

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/

Comment: Since this is tagged "multithreading", you may want to consider [Arrays.parallelSort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Comparator.

Given class Car:

```
class Car {
       private long distance;

       public long getDistance(){
          return this.distance;
       }

       public void setDistance(long distance){
          this.distance = distance;
       }
}
```

And Comparator DistanceComparator:

```
class DistanceComparator implements Comparator<Car> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Car a, Car b) {
        return a.distance < b.distance ? -1 : a.distance == b.distance ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Sort your Car object with the Comparator:

```
class Main{
    private static void main(String[] args){
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      List<Car> carList = foo.getAllCars();
      Collections.sort(car, new DistanceComparator());
    }
}
```